# weird overlay in RecyclerView when changing fragments (child frags)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-view

edit 1: the recyclerview has a fixed size *(300x500dp)*, it is because i wanted to check whether the overlay applies on the RecyclerView or the whole ViewGroup

---

i'm facing an issue with fragments and layouts, basically my app uses child fragments;
here's the rough hierarchy:

```
Activity
    |-> FrameLayout (MainFragment, RootView: CoordinatorLayout)
        |-> FrameLayout (ChildFragment, RootView: RelativeLayout)
        |   |-> RecyclerView
        |-> LinearLayout (CustomSearchView)
        |   |-> CardView
        |-> BottomAppBar
        |   |-> BottomNavigationView
        |-> FloatingActionButton
```

---

#### here's the gist to the code: https://gist.github.com/AwaisKing/12df079991558257307f40c8fa6a7d2d

and i'm trying to `replace` and `addToBackStack` a fragment, but whenever i do so it applies a light overlay on `RecyclerView`

i have tried adding `background`s to layouts and views, but i've had no luck.

i hope someone could help me with this issue

[image: the RecyclerView issue]

Comment: can you more concise about what each layout contain?

Comment: i'll edit the hierarchy in a second

Comment: You need to explain what "a light overlay" is and show some layout and code. Your "rough hierarchy" is not how we develop Android apps.

Comment: @dominicoder see the listview? it changes background color, if i set background to any other color it adds a new tint or something onto the background.

Comment: OK, but you've still not posted any code or xml layout, so all anyone can do is throw out random guesses based on your gif. For example, random guess: you have code that sets the list background to a light overlay. Don't do that. Did I solve your problem? :P

Comment: @dominicoder i have added the link to the code, see if you can find anything there smartypants

Comment: Check the layout for the item views, your app theme, and / or setting focusable to false on the recyclerview (looks like it's getting focused).

Comment: thank you @dominicoder IT WAS a focusable issue, all i had to do was set the `android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled` attr to `false`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to [@dominicoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197251/dominicoder) for giving me a nudge into the direction of fixing that! [comment #120480134](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68154118/weird-overlay-in-recyclerview-when-changing-fragments-child-frags?noredirect=1#comment120480134_68154118)

there is an attribute `android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled` all i had to do was set it to `false`

Answer (score 0):

There are some places you used CoordinatorLayout, this is basically a FrameLayout so view would be overlay if you don't configure it properly. As a glance those are  `frag_main.xml`, `int_frag_search.xml`

One more thing, I think you should only use child fragment when it is really nesscessary

Comment: nvm it was actually focus highlight issue, thanks to @dominicoder